# how to make Shortcut Context Menu to read and open zip file?

Tags: c#, zip, contextmenu, windows-explorer

I'm getting stack in creating a shortcut context menu to read zip file to my application automatically just like in one of those WinRar application.Can you give me some idea or resources on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is a *Shell Extension*.  Here's [some google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=explorer%20shell%20extension&aq=0&oq=explorer%20shell&sugexp=chrome,mod=9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) on the subject.

Another source: [The Complete Idiot's Guide to Writing Shell Extensions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens)